# $\log(z_1\cdot z_2\cdot \ldots \cdot z_n)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)+\ldots+\log(z_n)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this question:

Let $z_1, z_2,  \cdots , z_n$ be complex numbers

What conditions must be met  so that

$$\log(z_1\cdot z_2\cdot  \ldots \cdot z_n)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)+\ldots+\log(z_n)$$

---

For example consider $\log:\mathbb{C}/(-\infty,0]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ principal branch

$\log(z)=\log |z|+i\arg(z)$ where $\arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi)$

If $z_j\in \mathbb{C}/(-\infty,0]$ sucht that $\arg(z_j)\in(-\frac{\pi}{n},\frac{\pi}{n})$ then

$$\log(z_1\cdot z_2\cdot  \ldots \cdot z_n)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)+\ldots+\log(z_n)$$

---

Particular case if $\Re(z),\Re(w)>0$ then $$\log(z\cdot w)=\log(z)+\log(w)$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the question only on *sufficient* conditions?  Because otherwise, $z_1 = z_2 = \cdots = z_n = 1$ is sufficient (though not particularly satisfying).

Comment: If and only if $-\pi<\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n\le\pi$ where $-\pi<\theta_i\le\pi$ are the phases of the $z_i$s.

Comment: Where did you "come across" this?

Answer (score 0):

In view of the define of $\log(z)=\log|z|+i Arg(z) (z\neq 0)$, where $Arg(z)$ denote the argument of the complex number $z$. We note that
\begin{split}
&\log(z_{1}\cdot z_{2}\cdots z_{n})\\
&=\log(|z_{1}|\cdot|z_{2}|\cdots|z_{n}|)+i Arg(z_{1}\cdot z_{2}\cdots z_{n})\\
&=(\log|z_{1}|+\log|z_{2}|+\cdots+\log|z_{2}|)+i(Arg(z_{1})+Arg(z_{2})+\cdots+Arg(z_{n}))\\&=(\log|z_{1}|+iArg(z_{1}))+(\log|z_{2}|+iArg(z_{2}))+\cdots+(\log|z_{n}|+iArg(z_{n}))\\
&=\log(z_{1})+\log(z_{2})+\cdots+\log(z_{n}).
\end{split}

So $\log(z_{1}\cdot z_{2}\cdots z_{n})=\log(z_{1})+\log(z_{2})+\cdots+\log(z_{n})$ holds for all $z_{j}\neq 0,(j=1,\cdots,n)$.

Comment: The OP is referring to the set $logz$ you have proved it for the principal value $Logz$

Comment: Mod $Arg z_1+Arg z_2+\cdots+Arg z_n$ by $2\pi.$ Then your answer is perfect :)